# django admin list_display textfield

Tags: django, django-admin

I've a  Textfield  defined in **model.py**

In the **changelist** data are shown as *single line* instead

in the **change view** of the object, the  data are rendered in a:

> vLargeTextField

the break lines are mantained as in the user input.

> es.
>
> hi,
>
> nice to meet you,
>
> I need a break

Is there something special to allow the **list_display** to show the data as in the **change view**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can render breaks as html (the [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) templatetag make it easy, or surround with the html [pre tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) i.e. `<pre>... (your_text) ...</pre>`) and set the `allow_tags` property to `True` for this field within your admin class definition.

admin.py

```
class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = YourModel
    list_display = ['your_large_text_field__custom_rendering']

    def your_large_text_field__custom_rendering(self, obj):
        return "<pre>%s</pre>" % (obj.your_large_text_field,)
    your_large_text_field__custom_rendering.allow_tags = True


admin.site.register(YourModel, CustomAdmin)
```